# planted 100 tulip bulbs and they did not bloom

Tags: flowers, tulips

I planted over 100 tulip bulbs last fall and 20-30 daffodils.. The tulips never came up. Anyone know what could have caused this?  Thanks

Comment: Where do you live? Are similar flowers already blooming in your region? (Note: if your soils is colder (shadows), you may wait some more days, and if you are in a hot climate, bulbs should pass some days in fridge). How deep did you planted the bulbs? Ev. you could remove one bulb, and take a photo.

Comment: My tulips won't come up for another week. It depends on your region and the bulbs you've planted. Some are early spring, some are a few weeks in.

Comment: Do you have squirrels in your neighbourhood?  They are smart and will dig down three or four inches.

Comment: If you are in a warm location , I think  zone 7 or warmer, it is not cold enough in the winter. I have tried the recommendation of putting them in the refrigerator for 6 weeks in the winter and it did not work for me. That was in zone 8. Daffodils do not need chilling .

Comment: A bad supplier might be another cause, here in Amsterdam (known for tulips) we have many swindlers that sell bad quality bulbs to tourists.

Comment: @Debby, for people to be able to help you, they need to know the situation, as many details as possible as the causes can be infinite. If you could describe how , where, and when did you planted, and any other context relevant to your question, you'll receive answers that can pinpoint the causes... Welcome to StackExchange!